# Function within Function Python

Tags: python, function

This function converts celsius to fahrenheit

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit (ctemp):
        temp_convert_to_fahr=int((ctemp+32)*1.8)
```

This function prints the celsius to fahrenheit table

```
def print_celsius_to_fahrenheit_conversion_table(min,max):
    print("Celsius\tFahrenheit")
    print("------------------")
    for num  in range (min,max):
            tempc=num
            tempf= celsius_to_fahrenheit(tempc)
            print(tempc,"\t",tempf)
```

This function converts from fahrenheit to celsius

```
def fahrenheit_to_celsius(tempf):
    f_to_c=int((tempf-32)/1.8)
```

This function prints the fahrenheit to celsius table

```
def print_fahrenheit_to_celsius_conversion_table(min,max):
    print("Fahrenheit\tCelsius")
    print("------------------")
    for num in range (min,max):
            tempf=num
            tempc= fahrenheit_to_celsius(tempf)
            print(tempf,"\t",tempc)
print()
print_celsius_to_fahrenheit_conversion_table(0,11)
print()
print_fahrenheit_to_celsius_conversion_table(32,41)
```

Every time I run this, my column that is being converted shows up as "none", any help as to what is wrong?

Comment: Open and shut case, thanks guys, that was so simple I'm a little embarrassed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just assigning variables in your functions.  You aren't returning anything.  Just change `f_to_c=` and `temp_convert_to_fahr=` to `return`:

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit (ctemp):
    return int((ctemp+32)*1.8)

def fahrenheit_to_celsius(tempf):
    return int((tempf-32)/1.8)
```

Since you don't return anything explicitly, the functions return `None` implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get the value from a function you need to `return` the value from the function explicitly, otherwise Python automatically does `return None`.

Here's the corrected functions:

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit (ctemp):
    temp_convert_to_fahr=int((ctemp+32)*1.8)
    return temp_convert_to_fahr

def fahrenheit_to_celsius(tempf):
    f_to_c=int((tempf-32)/1.8)
    return f_to_c
```

Answer (score 0):

missing return statements in the functions

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit (ctemp):
    temp_convert_to_fahr=int((ctemp+32)*1.8)
    return temp_convert_to_fahr

def fahrenheit_to_celsius(tempf):
        f_to_c=int((tempf-32)/1.8)
       return f_to_c
```

**or**

```
 def celsius_to_fahrenheit (ctemp):
        return int((ctemp+32)*1.8)  
def fahrenheit_to_celsius(tempf):
       return int((tempf-32)/1.8)
```